# Can't deploy to Heroku. at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: java, spring, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku. And my app is crashed. This is errors:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" 
host=smartmed2017.herokuapp.com request_id=3e8cc17e-320b-4230-bdbb-
3a751e3477de fwd="195.19.247.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 
bytes= protocol=https

2017-06-01T11:17:42.380548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 
desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" 
host=smartmed2017.herokuapp.com request_id=9ab6574e-3fed-4af3-9cae-
0651e13d9112 fwd="195.19.247.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 
bytes= protocol=https
```

As usual, but I the reasons of this problem can be different.

This is Main.class

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/untitled-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

[Screenshot of my classes and pages here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwnEp.png)

Comment: Can you run `heroku logs -t` after restarting the dyno and capture the error message from the JVM?

Comment: @codefinger  [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxr_GNWk2oo0b3RJLW5OQU1SWG8). Thank you for your response

Comment: The log you posted is not detailed enough.
Try copying the log from the beginning and let us see what could have happened.

In case you have a database connecting to localhost, check and change the port.
Do you have webapp-runner added to pom.xml?

Comment: @AwotunboOlakunleOladeji I don't use any DB yet. [First screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxr_GNWk2oo0ZlI1SUIzRE13TjA), [Second one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxr_GNWk2oo0NE44VUtHcUlrSk0). I don't have this one.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AwotunboOlakunleOladeji I don't have webapp-runner, I mean

Answer (score 3):

H10 error means : A crashed web dyno or a boot timeout on the web dyno will present this error.
According to  [java-webapp-runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner#configure-maven-to-download-webapp-runner)

1. Add webapp runner to the plugins section in your pom.xml

   ```
    <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <artifactItems>
                           <artifactItem>
                               <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                               <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                               <version>8.5.11.3</version>
                               <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                           </artifactItem>
                       </artifactItems>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Change your Procfile to

`web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

Then try and redeploy.

Check out this project i deployed on github if it can help you more [Sample Project on Heroku](https://github.com/kunleawotunbo/Tunbor).

Can you share the project on github?

Comment: [Here is repo](https://github.com/vladyour/SmartMed2017.git)
There you will see logfile.txt. There is the errors after the changes

Answer (score 0):

After creating the "**Procfile**" inside of the root folder and setting below code on it, the server started working:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/my-nice-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Just make sure that:

1. **./gradlew build** works
2. **./gradlew bootRun** works

Documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#prerequisites